# How can I scrape this data when requests doesn't return it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape the information from this page:
`https://databases.usatoday.com/nfl-arrests/`

Each of the arrests is listed in a table on the page under the css selector: `#csp-data` I can see this in the page's source as well: `<div id="csp-data" class="csp-data"></div>` but there is nothing in-between those tags for me to parse.

When I try to run the following code, I return no results.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://databases.usatoday.com/nfl-arrests/"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

test = soup.select('#csp-data > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div.table-responsive > table > tbody')
print(test)
```

If I use `test = soup.select('#csp-data')`, I return `<div class="csp-data" id="csp-data"></div>` If I move to the next step `#csp-data > div`, I return no results.

I'm assuming that the data isn't being loaded when requests gets the data, but I'm not sure. When I go in through my browser and use inspect element, I can see the table has loaded.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could move forward here?

Comment: The table content looks to be loaded by AJAX request after the main page is loaded, you'd need to wait for the AJAX to complete before you can fetch the data in Python. I don't know if this can be done via requests or bs4. You might want to consider taking a look at Selenium instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working output from ajax calls

```
import requests
import json

body = 'action=cspFetchTable&security=3193d24eb0&pageID=10&blogID=&sortBy=Date&sortOrder=desc&page=1&searches={}&heads=true'
    

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}


url='https://databases.usatoday.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' 
r = requests.post(url, data=body, headers =headers)
tables =  r.json()['data']['Result']
for table in tables:
    print(table['First_name'])
```

Output:Example

```
Bradley
Deonte    
Barkevious
Darius    
Jarron    
Tamorrion 
Zaven     
Frank     
Justin    
Aldon     
Jeff      
Marshon   
Broderick 
Frank     
Jaydon    
Kevin     
Kemah     
Chad
Isaiah
Rashard
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Where did you look to locate the commands you have listed in your body variable?

Comment: Network tab> header Tab and below form data, click view source and copy  view parsed and finally put it into variable as string. Thanks